# Inno Setup - How to localize component and type names?

Tags: inno-setup

How to localize component and type names? For example:

```
[Languages]
Name: "eng"; MessagesFile: "Idiomas\English.isl"
Name: "spa"; MessagesFile: "Idiomas\Spanish.isl"
```

If I choose English:

```
[Types]
Name: "full"; Description: "Full installation"
Name: "compact"; Description: "Compact installation"
Name: "custom"; Description: "Custom installation"; Flags: iscustom

[Components]
Name: "program"; Description: "Program Files"; Types: full compact custom; \
    Flags: fixed
Name: "readme"; Description: "Readme File"; Types: full
```

or if I choose Spanish:

```
[Types]
Name: "full"; Description: "Instalación Completa"
Name: "compact"; Description: "Instalación Mínima"
Name: "custom"; Description: "Instalación Personalizada"; Flags: iscustom

[Components]
Name: "program"; Description: "Archivos de Programa"; Types: full compact custom; \
    Flags: fixed
Name: "readme"; Description: "Archivo de Ayuda"; Types: full
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Define [custom messages](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=custommessagessection) in the language files:

- `idiomas\English.isl`:

  ```
  [CustomMessages]
  FullInstallation=Full installation
  CompactInstallation=Compact installation
  CustomInstallation=Custom installation
  ProgramFilesComponent=Program Files
  ReadmeFileComponent=Readme File
  ```
- `idiomas\Spanish.isl`:

  ```
  [CustomMessages]
  FullInstallation=Instalación Completa
  CompactInstallation=Instalación Mínima
  CustomInstallation=Instalación Personalizada
  ProgramFilesComponent=Archivos de Programa
  ReadmeFileComponent=Archivo de Ayuda
  ```
- *or* you can use the `[CustomMessages]` section in the main .iss file:

  ```
  [CustomMessages]
  eng.FullInstallation=Full installation
  spa.FullInstallation=Instalación Completa
  ...
  ```

And then use these custom messages using the [`{cm:MessageName}` constant](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=consts&anchor=cm) in your script:

```
[Types]
Name: "full"; Description: "{cm:FullInstallation}"
Name: "compact"; Description: "{cm:CompactInstallation}"
Name: "custom"; Description: "{cm:CustomInstallation}"; Flags: iscustom

[Components]
Name: "program"; Description: "{cm:ProgramFilesComponent}"; \
  Types: full compact custom; Flags: fixed
Name: "readme"; Description: "{cm:ReadmeFileComponent}"; \
  Types: full
```

[image: English]

[image: Spanish]

Comment: Thanks a lot Martin!!